# VBA Code to copy the set of cells between two specific texts and transpose

Tags: vba, excel

First of all, must appreciate that you all are doing an incredible job by helping beginner like me. Would also request for your help on one of the queries, on VBA Excel task...

I am looking for a VBA code to COPY the set of cells from COLUMN1 exist between two specific text and TRANSPOSE that set of cells to COLUMN2...

Will try to make it clear by giving an example:

First thing VBA code starts reading Column1 --- Row1, Row2, Row3 and so on....

Now there is a text called "CLICK" at Row4.... And there is some "IMPORTANT INFO" from Row5 to Row8.... And there is a text called "VIEW" at Row9....

However I need to copy the "IMPORTANT INFO" (Row5 to Row8) from COLUMN1 and TRANSPOSE that to COLUMN2 > Row5...

Now moving forward after Row9, Row10, Row11... There again is the text "CLICK" reappearing at Row12..... And "IMPORTANT INFO"  from Row13 to Row16..... And text "VIEW" at Row17.... Again VBA code would copy the second set of cells Row13 to Row16 and TRANSPOSE that to COLUMN2 > Row13....

Overall there are multiple sets exist in COLUMN1 between "CLICK" and "VIEW".... VBA Code has to check the complete COLUMN1 and copy the sets of cells and Transpose that to COLUMN2...

Sorry if my explanation is confusing, if this looks difficult to understand, please share your email and I can send you the Spreadsheet on email.... Thanks for your time and help... PS:Have attached the pic of Excel for your reference

[image]

Comment: Would you mind use paragraphs, please? This is not readable.

Comment: And please get rid of the "fluff". (The bits telling people that they are doing a great job, and thanking them for their time, and similar things, do not help provide an explanation of the issue.  If you don't edit them out, someone else has to spend time doing so.)

Comment: And also include what code you are currently trying to get to work.  If you haven't written any code yet, then it is too early to be posting questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: and there is no pic attached as OP says in final sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always four rows below where you find the text "Click" that you want to transpose, then this would do that for you:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'Change the Sheet name above to the sheet you will be using
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A on your Sheet
For i = 1 To LastRow 'loop from row 1 to last
    FoundClick = InStr(ws.Cells(i, 1), "Click") 'check for text "Click" in cell
    If FoundClick > 0 Then ' if the text "Click" is found
        AddressFound = ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Address 'get the address of where Click was found
        AddressFound = Replace(AddressFound, "$", "")
        AddressTo = ws.Cells(i + 4, 1).Address 'get the next four rows below where it was found
        AddressTo = Replace(AddressTo, "$", "")

        Range(AddressFound & ":" & AddressTo).Copy 'copy the range, the four rows below where "Click" was found

        ws.Cells(i, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        'transpose onto column B
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Xabier - That works exactly the way I want. Excellent work done. I am extremely thankful for your time and kindness in turning up so prompt with accurate code. Once again many thanks for your help and time... And that looks so impressing that you picked-up the requirement and provided the code in no time - Amazing...